# How do I define binding validation rule in Textbox derived Custom Control

Tags: wpf, validation

So I am trying to create a textbox-derived Custom Control in WPF that will allow me to to provide Range for validation. So I could use my control like following

```
<RangeValidatedTextBox Min="0" Max="100" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
```

Now I found [this MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on how to implement validation of textboxes which is what I am using as a reference.

Now the issue with custom control is that you have an ability to provide Style where either you can provide `Template` which in this case will be defined by `TextBox` so I have the following style in my Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type customControls:ScoreTextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
```

Now, I would like to use the above Style to provide `Binding.ValidationRules` property value, I have tried this

```
   <Setter Property="Text">
    <Setter.Value>
        <TemplateBinding Property="Text" >
                    <TemplateBinding.ValidationRules>
                        <validation:MyRangeValidationRule
                    Min="{TemplateBinding Min}"
                    Max="{TemplateBinding Max}"
                    ></validation:MyRangeValidationRule>
            </TemplateBinding.ValidationRules>
    </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
```

But the above gives me compile errors because `TemplateBinding` wont take `ValidationRules`. Is there any way I can create a custom control that basically is just a `TextBox` with a specific type of binding validator ?